# Why does JPA require a no-arg constructor for domain objects?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

Why does JPA require a no-arg constructor for domain objects?
I am using eclipselink and just got this exception during deployment.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-63] (Eclipse Persistence Services-1.1.0.r3639-SNAPSHOT): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException

Exception Description: The instance creation method   
[com.me.model.UserVO.<Default Constructor>], with no parameters, 
  does not exist, or is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
  com.me.model.UserVO.<init>()
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.me.model.UserVO --> 
  [DatabaseTable(user)])
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because it often happens that the JPA provider has to instantiate your domain object dynamically. It cannot do so, unless there is a no-arg constructor - it can't guess what the arguments should be.

Comment: Does that also mean that the no-arg constructor might get called after persisting an entity (e.g. when the entity manager initially loads an entity). In this case, we should not initialize any fields or do some other work in the constructor, right?

Comment: @Theo - yes, the constructor is called when you load an entity.

Answer (score 15):

Also notice that this is **not** provider dependent. It is a JPA specification.

JPA v2.0 [JSR-317](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html) and v2.1 [JSR-338](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html) says:

*The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well.
The no-arg constructor must be public or protected*.

Comment: The links are broken