# JPA reference other entity in an entity constructor

Tags: java, jpa

In my database table Attribute, I will have a list of data loaded first. Every time, when I want to persist a new record of MyAttribute, I will need to search through the table Attribute first and select the appropriate record from table Attribute before I insert to table MyAttribute.

```
@Entity
class MyAttribute{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Attribute.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="attribute_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    Attribute detail;

    private String greet;

    public MyAttribute(){
        this.greet = "Hello World.";
        this.detail = new MyDbLayer().selectAttributeDetail("first"); //Error is thrown here.
    }

    //getter & setter
}

@Entity
class Attribute{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Index(name = "name_index")
    @Column(unique=true )
    private String name;

    //getter & setter
}

class MyDbLayer{
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public MyDbLayer() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPu");
    }

    public Attribute selectAttributeDetail(String name) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query queryGetAttribute = em.createQuery("select a from Attribute a where a.name = :attributeName");

        List<AttributeDescription> attributeDescList = queryGetAttribute.setParameter("attributeName", name).getResultList();

        AttributeDescription tempAttribute = null;

        if (!attributeDescList.isEmpty()) {
            tempAttribute = (AttributeDescription) attributeDescList.get(0);
        }

        em.clear();
        em.close();

        return tempAttribute;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why I keep on receiving error like:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPu] Unable
>   to build EntityManagerFactory
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor
>   for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate
>   test object

P.S. This is not the real code that I'm working on, but the structure is more or less the same.

Answer (score 3):

What about making a second construtor for MyAttribute?

```
public MyAttribute(){
    this.greet = "Hello World.";
    // this.detail = new MyDbLayer().selectAttributeDetail("first"); //Error is thrown here.
}

public MyAttribute(Attribute detail){
    this.greet = "Hello World.";
    this.detail = detail;
}
```

The default constructor is also used by jpa to load persited objects. this can cause unexpected behaviour

Comment: JPA *needs* a no-args constructor to work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808747/why-does-jpa-require-a-no-arg-constructor-for-domain-objects

Comment: But in this case, will I not rewrite a lot of the code that call MyAttribute? What if I want to reduce rewriting it in all different class that call the constructor?

Comment: Well I think you must find path of least resistance. Perhaps make a factory that builds the initialised Object for you and then search and replace 'new MyAttribute()' with the factory call

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the JPA model to be able to access an `EntityManager` from an Entity. It can be done, but it can have different behaviors depending on the implementation.

In your case accessing an `EntityManager` from the no args constructor is never a good idea. Because thats the constructor used by the `EntityManager` when it loads an Entity. So every time `MyAttribute` is loaded by an `EntityManager` you will try to create antoher `EntityManager` to initialise the `detail` relationship which will be overwritten by the first `EntityManager` using the value it loaded from the database.

Usually you should have a service layer which has access to an `EntityManager` that manages your JPA Entities.