# Why we are breaking JPA specification here?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, lombok, builder

I use Lombok and JPA in my program and I intend to create an Owner object with builder annotation, but in the BaseEntity file when I put @AllArgsConstructor on the class, IntelliJ gives me this warning and when I add @NoArgsConstructor The warning goes away:

> Using @Builder/@AllArgsConstructor for JPA entities without defined
> no-argument constructor breaks JPA specification.

BaseEntity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

Person:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(Long id,String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(id);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Owner:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "owner_id"))
public class Owner extends Person {

    @Builder
    public Owner(Long id,String firstName, String lastName, Set<Pet> pets, String address, String city, String telephone) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.pets = pets;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<>();
    private String address, city, telephone;

}
```

My question is why does the jpa specification break?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808747/why-does-jpa-require-a-no-arg-constructor-for-domain-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JPA Entity requires a no-arg constructor by [specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a18).